# Real conditional mixing future and past

Tags: conditional-constructions

Introduction - a friend asked me on chat if [a large, well known website] is down. I replied after 10 minutes that it was working for me. He replied that it was down during that time. Then I stated that we can check tomorrow news.

My first instinctive sentence was:

> If it's in the news, it means it was down

After thinking about it I am not sure if it is fully correct. Most mixed conditionals I found on the internet concerned unreal ones.

I guess that proper way might be with future perfect:

> If it's in the news, it means it will have been down

But it does not 'sound right' and I have a 'feeling' the original one is correct (then again - I'm not a native speaker) as the ending is too close to 3rd conditional. How to express it properly?

Comment: Maceiej, problems here is that ELL is practically down on Sunday because a lack of on-line users. I, as an expert of prepostions, cannot help you, but to me your 'instictive sentence' is right if you have alredy read the news.

Comment: If it's in the new, it'll mean it was down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a native speaker and and ESL teacher. Your instinctive answer, "If it's in the news, it means it was down," is absolutely correct. It's in the zero-conditional. Your instincts were right about the alternate answer, "If it's in the news, it means it will have been down," were spot on too. It isn't right.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a native either, but to me the first one sounds correct.
The second suggests the website *will* be down sometime in the future. The first suggests that the website *was* down and it's *not anymore* and thus there's no effect in the present.

There's also [this](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/futureperfectcontinuous.html) article at English Page regarding the Future Perfect Continuous Tense.